# XPath relative path in expression

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am in 'group' node. From it, I want to find such 'item' node, that has 'id' attribute equals to current's 'group' node 'ref_item_id' attribute value. So in my case, by being in 'group' node B, I want 'item' node A as output. This works:

```
<xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::item[@id='1']/@description"/>
```

But this doesn't (gives nothing):

```
<xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::item[@id=@ref_item_id]/@description"/>
```

When I type:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@ref_item_id"/>
```

I have '1' as result. So this attribute is for sure accessible, but I can't find path to it from XPath expression above. I tried many '../' combinations, but couldn't get it work.

Code to test: http://www.xmlplayground.com/7l42fo

Full XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <item description="A" id="1"/>
    <item description="C" id="2"/>
    <group description="B" ref_item_id="1"/>
</root>
```

Full XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="root">
     <xsl:for-each select="group">
        <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::item[@id=@ref_item_id]/@description"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Few questions for clarification. Can you have many <item> node with a particular id ? Are all the <item> nodes placed before the <group> nodes ?

Comment: @Ravz 'id' is unique within <item> nodes. All <item> are placed before <group>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has to do with **context**. As soon as you enter a predicate, the context becomes the node currently being filtered by the predicate, and **no longer** the node matched by the template.

You have two options - use a variable to cache the outer scope data and reference that variable in your predicate

```
<xsl:variable name='ref_item_id' select='@ref_item_id' />
<xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::item[@id=$ref_item_id]/@description"/>
```

or make use of the `current()` function

```
<xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::item[@id=current()/@ref_item_id]/@description"/>
```

Comment: Nit but somehow important, `current` is a function defined in XSLT http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-current, not in XPath.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression searches for an item whose id attribute matches its own ref_item_id. You need to capture the current ref_item_id in an xsl:variable and refer to that xsl:variable in the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the XML, if I assume that you have `<item>` and `<group>` as siblings and in any order.
Then a sample input XML would look like the following.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
        <item description="A" id="1"/>
        <item description="C" id="2"/>
        <group description="B" ref_item_id="1"/>
        <item description="D" id="1"/>
        <group description="E" ref_item_id="2"/>
    </root>
```

Now, if the goal is to extract the description of all the `<item>` nodes whose *id* is matching with corresponding `<group>` *nodes ref_item_id*. Then we can simply loop over only such `<item>` nodes and get their description.

```
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
      <xsl:template match="root">
         <xsl:for-each select="//item[(./@id=following-sibling::group/@ref_item_id) or (./@id=preceding-sibling::group/@ref_item_id)]">
            <xsl:value-of select="./@description"/>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Since you say that  nodes are having unique id and all  nodes are placed before  nodes.
I would recommend you to use the following XSL and loop over specific  nodes instead of  nodes.

```
 <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
      <xsl:template match="root">
         <xsl:for-each select="//item[./@id=following-sibling::group/@ref_item_id]">
            <xsl:value-of select="./@description"/>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Ravz Thanks for another idea, but this won't work in my case, because in for-each I select <group> and I analyze it further, and this solution lefts me with <item> in for-each. I need to have access to <group> and from <item> I need only 'description'.

Comment: OK. I assumed that you are only extracting the description. In that case this solution will not work and you need to use the variable approach as described in 1st solution by @Utkanos.

Answer (score 0):

One more possible solution using `xsl:key`

```
<xsl:key name="kItemId" match="item" use="@id" />

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:for-each select="group">
        <xsl:value-of select="key('kItemId', @ref_item_id)[1]/@description"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```